# Sentry: All console logs show breadcrumb rather than file in browser

Tags: ionic-framework, sentry

I have an Ionic app and after adding sentry-cordova, I noticed that my console logs (in browser) now show the following:

[image]

Previously, it would name the file and line number rather than "breadcrumbs" and I have no idea how to change this behavior.

It's worth noting that when I hover over `breadcrumbs.js` in the logs it references: `@sentry/browser`

Comment: which version of sentry cordova plugin are you using?

Comment: `"sentry-cordova": "^0.17.0"`

Comment: Can you please try the latest bits we've been experimenting: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cordova/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc.0

Comment: @BrunoGarcia I installed it and now every log says: `instrument.js:109` rather than `breadcrumbs`.  I'm considering fully uninstalling and re-installing as I never used to have this issue

Comment: tried reinstalling and I still see the same thing.  Is there a way to have logging exclude sentry in browser?

Comment: I suggest raising an issue on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much a solution as a potential workaround but it did the trick for me and should work for anyone using environment variables.

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: "___DSN___",
  integrations: function(integrations) {
    return integrations.filter(function(integration) {
      if (!environment.production) {
        // Disables breadcrumbs unless in production mode
        return integration.name !== "Breadcrumbs"
      }
    })
  }
});
```